# Python error loading plugin "MetaSearch"

Tags: qgis, python, error

On starting QGIS I receive the following message:
WARNING    Python error : Couldn't load plugin 'MetaSearch' due to an error when calling its classFactory() method See message log (Python Error) for more details.

I'm running QGIS 3.24.3., under Fedora 36, KDE spin.

Is this known?  Is there a fix, or?

The following appears under Python error log tab:

```
2022-06-15T09:47:38     CRITICAL    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 423, in _startPlugin
              plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
              from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/plugin.py", line 34, in 
              from MetaSearch.dialogs.maindialog import MetaSearchDialog<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/dialogs/maindialog.py", line 48, in 
              from MetaSearch.dialogs.manageconnectionsdialog import ManageConnectionsDialog<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/dialogs/manageconnectionsdialog.py", line 35, in from MetaSearch.util import (get_connections_from_file, get_ui_class,<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/plugins/MetaSearch/util.py", line 38, in 
              from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)<br />
File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 12, in 
              from .environment import Environment<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)<br />
File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 25, in 
              from .defaults import BLOCK_END_STRING<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)<br />
File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/defaults.py", line 3, in 
              from .filters import FILTERS as DEFAULT_FILTERS # noqa: F401<br />
File "/app/share/qgis/python/qgis/utils.py", line 888, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)<br />
File "/app/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/filters.py", line 13, in 
              from markupsafe import soft_unicode<br />
ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)<br />
```

Comment: Whats the version of the python package "markupsafe"? To get the version open the terminal, enter the python interpreter by typing ```python3``` then that you are in the python interpreter type:

```import markupsafe```

```markupsafe.__version__```

Comment: The response by python to the command as shown is:   "File "<stdin>", line 1
    import markupsafe markupsafe.__version__".  <br />If I drop that and simply run "import markupsafe" I am informed: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe'"

Comment: I'm not completely sure but maybe you can solve this installing the `markupsafe` module in python.

Comment: It is installed, but not apparently where the plugin expects it.  I'm not at all certain how critical the plugin - Metasearch - is to QGIS.